# How to dynamically add item to a Dojo AndOrReadStore

Tags: javascript, dojox.grid.datagrid, dojo

I have a Dojo(1.7) data grid backed by an `AndOrWriteStore` data store. Currently, the datagrid is static i.e. the store gets initialized once from a JSON datasource and the grid gets populated on screen. This all work fine.

However, how can I add data to the grid dynamically? i.e. add an item after its been initialized with some data. I've tried to look around with no success.

Comment: Have you tried simply adding to the store (`store.newItem({foo: "fooValue", bar: "barValue", bit: "bitValue"});`)?

Comment: Thanks BuffaloBuffalo, it worked, however the parent row appears fine, but when I expand it using the '+' button, I get the error `Error: dojox.data.AndOrReadStore: Invalid item argument.`